# Sqlite db re-arrange row

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am using a sqlite db in my Android application and I want my db to rearrange rows when user changes the order. It should affect all other rows so that I can show the data in order it was saved last time.

The image below shows my db. If I move the 2nd row to 6th position, my 3rd row should be 2nd, 4th should be 3rd and so on until 6th. How to do it using a query?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Simply save the field list in the order you want in the SharedPreferences. Then use that list in your next queries. After all, who is going to use `SELECT *`, anymore, in the 21st century?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect in your code (not sqlite) from which position to which other the item it's been moved. With that information you can create a sql statement to increment or decrement the affected positions. I mean (pseudocode):

**user moves item from position *n* to position *m***

```
// increment position
if (m > n) {
    // move other items
    executeSQL("UPDATE table_name SET list_position = list_position-1 WHERE list_position > n AND list_position <= m");
    // move
    executeSQL("UPDATE table_name SET list_position = m WHERE list_position = n");
}
// decrement position
else if (m < n) {
    // move other items
    executeSQL("UPDATE table_name SET list_position = list_position+1 WHERE list_position >= m AND list_position < n");
    // move
    executeSQL("UPDATE table_name SET list_position = m WHERE list_position = n");
}
```

Comment: In the same application I want a ListView with **swipe** to show multiple buttons as well **drag** the item to any place. I tried those with separate files but when I am trying to integrate the files I can't. Is there any simple way to solve this by single library?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know if there are any library that performs that, maybe. But if you don't find any solution I think that is better ask a new question.

Comment: what is n and what is m

Comment: According to my answer: "user moves item from position n to position m". So n is the starting position, and m the ending position. E.g: move from 5 to 9. n = 5; m = 9

Answer (score 3):

In fact it can be done with a single query. Just interpolate `:table` and `:col` writing the actual table and column names statically into your query, while `:curpos` and `:newpos` will have to be interpolated at every call (possibly using string concatenation as in the other answers, or whatever you see fit, e.g. a `java.util.Formatter` instance)

```
update :table set :col = 
  case 
    when :col < :curpos then :col + 1
    when :col > :curpos then :col - 1
    else :newpos
  end 
where :col between min(:curpos,:newpos) and max(:curpos,:newpos);
```

**Edited:** I found out that in the previous version there were a couple of useless lines...

Answer (score 1):

This is the snippet I used in my db for something similar:

```
if(newPosition < currentPosition) {
    db.rawQuery("UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " +
                Entry.COLUMN_NAME_ORDER + " = " + Entry.COLUMN_NAME_ORDER + "+1 "
                + "WHERE " + /* any additional requirements as needed */
                + Entry.COLUMN_NAME_ORDER + " BETWEEN " + newPosition + " AND " + currentPosition,
               null);
} else if(newPosition > currentPosition) {
    db.rawQuery("UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " +
                Entry.COLUMN_NAME_ORDER + " = " + Entry.COLUMN_NAME_ORDER + "-1 "
                + "WHERE " /* any additional requirements as needed */
                + Entry.COLUMN_NAME_ORDER + " BETWEEN " + currentPosition + " AND " + newPosition,
                null);
}
```

It changes order for every entry between currentPosition and newPosition, the only difference between if and else if block being in which direction, i.e. +1 or -1. I'm not sure whether there's a nicer way of handling this, but this has worked for me so far.

And lastly move the required item:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(1);
cv.put(Entry.COLUMN_NAME_ORDER, newPosition);
db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, Entry.COLUMN_NAME_ID + "=" + id, null);
```

Comment: what does the **Entry** here you mean. Now I am trying to do with the sqlite DB_Browser ..

Comment: @1992 Entry is just a static nested class holding the class names as static final Strings and implementing BaseColumns. You can hardcode the column names instead of that if you wish

Comment: @Luke Note that there is a small mistake in your code: when `newPosition < currentPosition` the `WHERE` condition must be `" BETWEEN " + newPosition + " AND " + currentPosition`.

Comment: @Dario I don't have SQLite handy to test it, but PostgreSQL query seems to confirm your comment. Strangely enough, this seemed to worked well so far. Anyway, I have edited it in the question

Answer (score 0):

Nearly right, but this works better:

```
// increment position
if (m > n) {
    // move original out of way
    executeSQL("UPDATE table_name SET list_position = 1000 WHERE list_position = n");
    // move other items
    executeSQL("UPDATE table_name SET list_position = list_position-1 WHERE list_position > n AND list_position <= m");
    // move original to new posn
    executeSQL("UPDATE table_name SET list_position = m WHERE list_position = 1000");
}
// decrement position
else if (m < n) {
    // move original out of way
    executeSQL("UPDATE table_name SET list_position = 1000 WHERE list_position = n");
    // move other items
    executeSQL("UPDATE table_name SET list_position = list_position+1 WHERE list_position >= m AND list_position < n");
    // move original to new posn
    executeSQL("UPDATE table_name SET list_position = m WHERE list_position = 1000");
}
```